# HTML image to pdf convertor in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf-generation, jspdf

HTML CODE:

```
<img class="imagepdf "src="www.images.com/someimage" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
```

I want to convert this image  to pdf format. I am using **jspdf()** for this but i am not getting my output ?Can someone  give me live example on fiddle for pdf conversion for chrome.

Comment: Why not just read the [documentation](http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/doc/symbols/jsPDF.html), it's pretty straigh forward, and make sure you have your console open and check for errors.

Comment: i have used both addimage and addhtml method i am not getting my output ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is code from it's github site

```
var getImageFromUrl = function(url, callback) {
    var img = new Image();

    img.onError = function() {
        alert('Cannot load image: "'+url+'"');
    };
    img.onload = function() {
        callback(img);
    };
    img.src = url;
}


var createPDF = function(imgData) {
    var doc = new jsPDF();



    doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 10, 10, 50, 50, 'monkey');
    doc.addImage('monkey', 70, 10, 100, 120); // use the cached 'monkey' image, JPEG is optional regardless



    doc.output('datauri');
}

getImageFromUrl('thinking-monkey.jpg', createPDF);
```

If you are working in chrome  security restrictions that prevent it from loading images from a url so just add this line and it will be working fine
**img.crossOrigin = " ";**
 It will be fine for chrome alse

Answer (score 0):

My answer is only for those who needs, to convert png to pdf from HTML, as I found this helpful, hence wanted to post it

I actually used this in my react file (**convert html -> image -> pdf**)

```
i used 2 packages : htmlToImage and the above jsPDF

import { jsPDF } from 'jspdf';

  


htmlToImage.toPng(document && document.getElementById('ticket'),
     {     quality: 1, backgroundColor: '#ffffff' })
          .then(function(dataUrl) {
            var doc = new jsPDF();
            doc.addImage(dataUrl, 'PNG', 15, 40, 180, 180);
            doc.save('pension-report' + '.pdf');
          });
    }


Explanation

for my project, I need to convert the set of divs into an image file which I did using htmlToImage
.
htmlToImage gives me in png format as it has a bunch of other different option .toCanvas etc
```