# Converting Image to PDF(shrinkage/one page getting loaded)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, pdf, jspdf

> Please do not mark this as duplicate, because I have tried many
>   things written on StackOverflow/Google & things did not work out.

***My requirement***:

Convert HTML div to Image & the convert Image to PDF.
So currently I am able to convert HTML div to Image & partially successful in converting that Image to PDF.

I am using **JsPDF** for conversion of Image to PDF.

Below is the code I have 2 cases:

1. Where pdf is getting generated, but Image is very shrunk.
2. Where there is no shrinkage, but only one page is getting generated.

Below I have shared images of both these cases..!!!

Plz, help me with this issue.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
  setTimeout(function(){
   downloadImage();
  },1000)
 });
 
 var base64 = "";
 function downloadImage(){

  //Case 1: Where the image gets shrinked.
     html2canvas(document.querySelector("#dvContainer")).then(canvas => {
  a = document.createElement('a'); 
  document.body.appendChild(a); 
  base64 = canvas.toDataURL();
  var doc = new jsPDF();
     var image = base64;
     doc.addImage(image, 'JPEG', 10, 10, 180, 160);
     doc.save('Report');
 }); 

  //Case 2: Where only 1 page gets loaded.
        html2canvas(document.querySelector("#dvContainer")).then(canvas => {
     a = document.createElement('a'); 
  document.body.appendChild(a); 
  base64 = canvas.toDataURL(wid = canvas.width, hgt = canvas.height);
  var doc = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');
  var image = base64;
  var hratio = hgt/wid;
  var width = doc.internal.pageSize.width;    
        var height = width * hratio;
     doc.addImage(image, 'JPEG',20,20, width, height);
     doc.save('Report');
 }); 
 }
  
</script>
```

[image: CASE 1]
[image: CASE 2]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML image to pdf convertor in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24908067/html-image-to-pdf-convertor-in-javascript)

Comment: No..That didnt work for me...This is little diffrerent issue

Comment: You can do it using jsPDF

Comment: I am using JsPdf already..Some small tweak is required for which I need help

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle for it? Possibly it is something that is to do with CSS.

Comment: Actually cant provide fiddle for it, but shall I share images of my problem??

Comment: OK. Is it possible to share the CSS which you have used for Image and its parent DIV?

Comment: @MohitKulkarni you can resize your image before `addImage` in jsPDF  based on A4 size

Comment: @NarendraJadhav Actually I had tried passing different parameters in constructor of jsPDF() before addImage() based on A4.
eg - jsPDF("a", "mm", "a4") &
jsPDF("p", "pt", "a4").
Fo you know any way of resizing image wrt need??

Comment: @MohitKulkarni Check this **[fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/2j0t)** hope this will help you