# Download a file as PDF

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to coding so I don't really know if this makes any sense haha but at my work we use this script to save a file as an image. My boss asked if I could make a script to download it as a PDF file. Is there a way to convert this script to save as image to download as PDF or something like that?

```
 <%-- Script to save as image --%>
            <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
                    $("#btnSave").click(function () {
                        $("div[id*=divCorpoCC").removeClass('table-responsive');
                        $("div[id*=divCorpoCC").css("width", "455");

                        html2canvas($("div[id*=divCorpoCC"), {
                            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                                theCanvas = canvas;
                                document.body.appendChild(canvas);

                                Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas);

                                //// Convert and download as image
                                //Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas)
                                ////Directs the image to the div
                                //$("#img-out").append(canvas);
                                ////Clean up
                                $("div[id*=divCorpoCC").addClass('table-responsive');
                                $("div[id*=divCorpoCC").css("width", "");
                                document.body.removeChild(canvas);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });</script>
```

This code downloads a file as an image. I need a button that downloads the file as a PDF file... I don't know if it's possible to do that without putting a url to download the file from...

Comment: you must convert the image to a pdf first. This can be done with jspdf https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf. Afterwards create a pdf and put the image inside the pdf like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24908067/html-image-to-pdf-convertor-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

The following code has **NOT** been tested but I think it should work:

```js
            <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
                    $("#btnSave").click(function () {
                        $("div[id*=divCorpoCC").removeClass('table-responsive');
                        $("div[id*=divCorpoCC").css("width", "455");

                        html2canvas($("div[id*=divCorpoCC"), {
                            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                                theCanvas = canvas;
                                document.body.appendChild(canvas);

                                // Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas);
                                canvas.save("download.pdf");
                                //// Convert and download as image
                                //Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas)
                                ////Directs the image to the div
                                //$("#img-out").append(canvas);
                                ////Clean up
                                $("div[id*=divCorpoCC").addClass('table-responsive');
                                $("div[id*=divCorpoCC").css("width", "");
                                document.body.removeChild(canvas);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });</script>
```

Sidenote: This is how I did it in one of my scripts, I don't know if it applies here though.